# mount EBS volume from one host to totally different host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Here is my problem:

- Deleted attachments from an app we're using
- Attempted a restore from backup but unfortunately the app was not set up to back up needed attachments

The app is hosted in AWS on an EBS-backed volume. I would like to attempt to create a volume from an earlier snapshot which contains the needed attachment files. The question is have is, ServerA is the prod server and ServerB is the staging server, both with completely different/unique FQDNs, if I were to mount the volume from ServerA into ServerB, would that cause any problems with ServerA?

I have tested the mounting method and i know it works. I can mount the volume and then from within the instance, I can mount the volume to a virtual device and then mount that virtual device to a mount point. From there, I can access the files and copy as needed. I just don't want to mess up anything on ServerA since it contains our prod application. Has anyone done this before? Will mounting an earlier snapshot of ServerA onto ServerB cause problems for the live version of ServerA??

Sorry for the confusing explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Amazon EBS volume can only be attached to one Amazon EC2 instance at a time.

If you have created a new EBS volume from an EBS snapshot, then it is a totally separate volume and may be attached to any instance (prod/non-prod, any VPC, etc) within that Availability Zone. (You nominate the AZ when creating the Volume from the Snapshot.)

No danger will result from mounting your 'restored' volume on any instance. It will not impact your production system. Just think of it like plugging a portable USB drive into a computer -- it will not impact any other drive.

Comment: Hi @Niag, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.